# How to have a floating menu in the middle of the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

Is this possible without the help of javascript?

Typically we have menu bars at the top of the page - we place them as a child of `body` and then absolutely position them e.g. `top: 10px; right: 10px;`.

What if we want to achieve the same goal but as a context menu further down the page?

I have started a fiddle to give an idea - here there's no positioning, we just have the default of `overflow: visible`.

I can't absolutely position it because I don't know the x,y due to the dynamic nature of the content that precedes it.

The only way I can think of is go down the traditional route of the top nav bar, and with javascript find the x,y of it's container and position it there. However I would need to manage that if the content that precedes it changes then it's position needs to change also.

Does anyone know of a "stick-to" jquery method. Or even better achieve it with pure css?

Thanks

here's my crude fiddle - click "one" http://jsfiddle.net/hHR23/1/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want this but I'm not certain from your description:

http://jsfiddle.net/samih/hHR23/2/

Notice this:

```
.section {
    height: 58px;
    background-color: yellow;
    position: relative;
}
```

And this:

```
.menu {
    position: absolute;

}
```

Now your menu will follow with the "dynamic" page because the absolute position is relative to the "position: relative" container.

Comment: as simple as that? - I had assummed it would not grow outside it's container

Answer (score 0):

Another approach - [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hHR23/3/).

HTML

```
<div class='header'>Header</div>
<div class='floatingmenu'>
  <ul class="menu">
    <li>One
      <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li>one a</li>
                <li>one b</li>
                <li>one c</li>
                <li>one d</li>
                <li>one e</li>
                <li>one f</li>
                <li>one g</li>
      </ul>
   </li>
   <li>Two</li>
   <li>Three</li>
   </ul>
</div>
```

CSS

```
 .header {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: blue;
}
.floatingmenu {
    width: 30%;
    height: 30%;
    background-color: green;
    color: white;
    border: 10px solid white;
    border-radius: 10px;
    margin: 20px auto;
}
.footer  {
    height: 200px;
    background-color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Do you mean "cover up" the content, or have the content wrap around it?